# What happens to objects when interpreter shuts down

Tags: python

I'm a bit confused what is happening to objects when Python interpreter shuts down. 
If I write a little code like that

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __del__(self):
        print "I'm going away"

o = MyClass()
```

and run it, I'll get this

```
I'm going away
```

My understanding is that when interpreter shuts down it will delete all references to created objects and these objects will run `__del__()` if specified (because ref count for them is 0).

My confusion is because:

1. I'm not able to find any documentation that says that python will clear all references on exit.
2. I'm confused why it's cleaning objects when the memory is about to be returned to the OS and declared *free* anyway. I guess in complex systems there's a big cost of deleting objects in memory that is about to be free anyway.
3. Reading docs about `__del__()` I see this `It is not guaranteed that __del__() methods are called for objects that still exist when the interpreter exits.` And it's getting a bit more complicated, are they saying that it's not guaranteed to be run because of some cycle dependancies or it's just not guaranteed? Who decides that?

So my questions are:

1. Who called `__del__` in my example above
2. Why it's not `guaranteed` to be called when I don't have reference cycles

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  The documentation that you quoted says that `__del__` is not guaranteed to be called for objects that exist when the interpreter exits.  Not just those with reference cycles; none of them.  In general, you cannot assume that your `__del__` method will ever be called.

Comment: I think I'm asking 2 questions, first, who called __del__ in my example above, second is why it's not guaranteed when I don't have cycles.

Comment: What the documentation means is that `__del__` may or may not be called for objects that exist when the interpreter exits.  It looks like in your case it was called, but that was basically luck; you can't rely on the fact that it will be called or not be called.  As for your second question, I don't know the technical reasons, but that's just how it is.  The documentation is clear that that's how it works.

Comment: `__del__` might be used e.g. to finish up writing the end of a file before it closes. BrenBarn is correct to say these finalizers aren't considered reliable, so it's a bit of an antipattern to do that, but AFAIK it's not just luck - if you have a reference cycle, the GC can't know which object in that cycle (if any) it can safely clean up first. If you know there can't be reference cycles (which are rare outside of data structures) there shouldn't be a problem. C++ doesn't provide GC, so can provide reliable destructor cleanup - with it's own provisos.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the point of the first question, but for CPython 2.7.8, `__del__` is called by `PyInstanceObject.instance_dealloc`, which is registered as the `tp_dealloc`, which is called when `Py_DECREF` is called and the reference count reaches zero. So, let's just say the interpreter calls it, not Python code. If you're asking that question with the hope that you can change how or when it gets called, I don't think it's possible.

As to why it's not guaranteed, to do that you'd have to go through all modules deleting their variables before exit, but if the `__del__` methods rely on any global variables, there's no simple way to guarantee a safe order for them to be executed. I'm not saying it's impossible, like with reference cycles, I'm saying it's complicated.

I imagine this was discussed at some point but the community or the BDFL decided it wasn't worth the hassle. I believe I saw some discussion about this years ago, but I couldn't find it now. Use of the `__del__` method was never encouraged in the first place, and if you need to guarantee some destructor method is called, you might be better using context managers for that.

Comment: There's also not wanting to add another strict burden to competing implementations.

Comment: Are you saying that as an hypothesis or you know it was the case? It makes sense, no doubt, but I don't know if that was considered back then.